# Incremental Average - Vectorized

Tags: python, time-series

Is there a way to transform the for loop in IncrementalAvg().Avg() to a vectorized form in numpy? Instead of going through each entry in the input time series X a vectorized approach could be much more efficient. Ideally, np.mean() and IncrementalAvg().Avg() should produce the same outcome as in the example provided below.

```
import numpy as np

class IncrementalAvg:

    def __init__(self, avg=None, counter=0):
        self.avg = avg
        self.counter = counter
        pass

    def Avg(self, X):
        # x is a 1D vector
        if self.avg is None:
            self.avg = np.mean(X)
            self.counter = X.size
        else:
            for x in X:
                self.counter += 1
                self.avg = self.avg + ((x - self.avg) / self.counter)



X = np.random.randn(10, 10)

IA = IncrementalAvg()

B = []

for x in X:

    B += list(x)
    IA.Avg(x)

    print(np.mean(B), IA.avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

UPD: both approaches in this answer are based on storing sum of elements. As an advantage: they are "loopless". Disadvantage: they may suffer from overflow in case of really large arrays

## Simple way

You can store average, upon every call `Avg()` method, transform this average into sum of all elements, those were ever passed to this class and recalculate average with new data. Like this:

```py
class IncrementalAvg:
    
    ....
    
    # Only Avg method will be modified
    def Avg(self, X):
        X = np.array(X)
        # x is a 1D vector
        if self.avg is None:
            self.avg = np.mean(X)
            self.counter = X.size
        else:
            sum = self.avg * self.counter
            sum += X.sum()
            self.counter += len(X)
            self.avg = sum / self.counter
```

## Beatiful way

What personally I find more "beautiful" is creating a custom getter method for `avg` field of the class. This way average will only be computed upon accessing `avg` field. It can be done like this:

```py
class IncrementalAvg:

    def __init__(self, avg=None, counter=0):
        self.avg = None
        self.sum = counter * avg if avg else 0
        self.counter = counter
        pass

    def Avg(self, X):
        X = np.array(X)
        # x is a 1D vector
        if self.avg is None:
            self.avg = np.mean(X)
            self.sum = X.sum()
            self.counter = X.size
        else:
            self.sum += X.sum()
            self.counter += len(X)
        return self.avg
  
    @property
    def avg(self):
        if counter != 0:
            return self.sum / self.counter
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: Hi @Евгений Крамаров thank you for your good answer. As you said, your answer solves the problem but it may cause overflow that is exactly what happens to me :(